# PyAudio python questions

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
CHUNK = 1024

data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
```

What does "CHUNK" means?
If data is equal to `wf.readframes(CHUNK)` why does it reads again every `while`?
Shouldn't I just write `data` to stream and then close it?

Comment: `CHUNK` will be replaced by 1024. In this case, it's reading 1024 byte chunks of the audio, writing it to the stream, and then reading another 1024 bytes until there's nothing left to read.

Answer (score 0):

`CHUNK` is 1024, so the code could be replaced with this:

```
data = wf.readframes(1024)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(1024)
```

Here's what's happening:

1. Reads in 1024 bytes from `wf` into data.
2. If data isn't empty, start looping:

   1. Write out the most recent bytes to `stream`.
   2. Read in the next 1024 bytes from `wf`.
   3. Start loop over again.

So, it's basically just writing out everything contained in `wf`. It just so happens it's reading that out in 1024 bytes segments (as defined by `CHUNK`).

Comment: Shouldn't it be "data = wf.readframes(1024*i)" since every turn we should read the next 1024 bytes, not the first 1024 bytes every time?

Comment: @user2483347 I'd guess it's consuming those bytes so it'll hand off the next 1024, but I'm not certain - I haven't worked with PyAudio.